# Want to solve immediate Access VBA related question

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I want to open a report namely "Invoice" (based on a query, which is joint with different two tables namely Customer Details and Product Details) by clicking a command button based on three different combobox namely Customer type, Name of the Customer and Cash memo number. I created a code given bellow and get error....Please help.

Code: DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acViewReport, , "[Customer Type] = " & Me.ltyp and [Name of the Customer] = " & Me.lcnm And [Cash Memo/Tax Invoice Number] = " & Me.lmnum, acWindowNormal"

DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acViewReport, , "[Customer Type] = " & Me.ltyp and [Name of the Customer] = " & Me.lcnm And [Cash Memo/Tax Invoice Number] = " & Me.lmnum, acWindowNormal"

Please resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. You have to differentiate between text and numbers. Assuming that [Customer Type] and [Name of the Customer] are text and [Cash Memo/Tax Invoice Number] is a number, it should look like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acViewReport, , "[Customer Type] = '" & Me.ltyp & "' and [Name of the Customer] = '" & Me.lcnm & "' And [Cash Memo/Tax Invoice Number] = " & Me.lmnum, acWindowNormal
```

Text must be always put in quotes, numbers not.